# Inserting a new element to array

Tags: arrays

So my goal is to join two Arrays together and insert the new size of the new array in the beginning of the array.

Comment: You allocate an array of size `n + m` but your first iteration of the top `for` accesses `n + m + 1` (which is off by 2).  As an aside, I'd suggest dropping the pointer arithmetic and just using array access.

Comment: Why are you writing code like `*(a1 + 0)` instead of `a1[0]`? I know it works be these are arrays so use the clearer array syntax. The "shift elements forward" loop makes no sense, it's a freshly allocated array and there's nothing to "shift".

Comment: I have to use pointers and pointer arithmetic for this assignment

Comment: First insert the elements into the new array.

Comment: @Xenikh You don't need to "shift" anything. Just copy the values into the new array.

Comment: Sorry, my bad..

Comment: I'm not just copying the elements into the new array, I also have to add a new element to the front of the new array which is the size of the new array. I'll try your idea @Xenikh

Comment: Shouldn't the final array be `{9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40}`? The first element of each source array is the array size (correct?) so you don't want to copy those values to the final array.

Comment: Yes that's correct and yes we can copy elements to the final array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to avoid manually writing code to copy array elements over "1 by 1", there are facilities in the language and standard libraries to do this for you.

This is the modern C++ way to do it:

```
short* ConcatArray(short* a1, short* a2)
{
    size_t len1 = a1[0];
    size_t len2 = a2[0];

    short* a3 = new short[len1 + len2 + 1]; // +1 for new length

    *a3 = (short)(len1 + len2 + 1);
    std::copy_n(a1, len1, a3+1);
    std::copy_n(a2, len2, a3 + 1 + len1);

    return a3;
}
```

Old "C" way (using new as allocator):

```
short* ConcatArray(short* a1, short* a2)
{
    size_t len1 = a1[0];
    size_t len2 = a2[0];

    short* a3 = new short[len1 + len2 + 1]; // +1 for new length

    *a3 = (short)(len1 + len2 + 1);
    memcpy(a3+1, a1, sizeof(*a1)*len1);
    memcpy(a3+1+len1, a2, sizeof(*a2)*len2);


    return a3;
}
```

Comment: This also might be a case for `std::copy_n`. The difference is mostly cosmetic but some people might think it's clearer.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - agreed. It does look better with `copy_n`. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, the only problem I'm having is not getting the last value from array 2

Comment: @StephDev - I had a typo. Instead of `*a3 = (short)(len1 + len2);` it should be `*a3 = (short)(len1 + len2 + 1);`  This has been fixed above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to shift values if you copy them to the correct position in the first place. This should do what you want.

```
short int *ConcatArray(short int *a1, short int *a2)
{
    short int n = a1[0]; // size of array 1
    short int m = a2[0]; // size of array 2
    short int newSize = n + m + 1;

    short int *newArr = new short int[newSize];

    int i = 0; // current output position in newArr
    newArr[i++] = newSize;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j, ++i) { // copy a1
        newArr[i] = a1[j];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j, ++i) { // copy a2
        newArr[i] = a2[j];
    }

    return newArr;
}
```

Here's the code working on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vfr7ao).

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem as before, the first two elements in the two original arrays aren't in the new one. Thank you for helping me

Comment: @StephDev Do you want the 5 values in the new array? That is a simple change that I just made.

Comment: Yes please, we’re allowed to have duplicates so having two of the same numbers in the array is okay.

Comment: For some reason I'm still not getting the 5 values from both arrays

Comment: @StephDev The code does work. You can see it compiled and running, [here on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vfr7ao).